# Detect black/almost black JPG images in PERL

Tags: image, perl, colors, detection, perlmagick

I want to detect the black/almost black JPEG images from a folder using PERL. 
Do you have any suggestions about the method/module that I should use?

Comment: [Image::Magick](http://p3rl.org/Image::Magick)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dark images will generally have a low-ish mean pixel value.

You can get the mean of the image's pixels using ImageMagick's `identify` at the command line like this:

```
identify -format "%[mean]" input.png
```

or using

```
identify -verbose input.png
```

and looking for the parameter you think will help most.

Or use `Perl` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;

my $image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->ReadImage("c.png");

print $image->Get("%[mean]");
```

In the Perl case, the range is 0-65535, so dark ones will have a mean below say 5,000.

**Example:**

Here is a dark image:

[image]

```
identify -format "%[mean]" dark.jpg
16914.6
```

And here is a lighter one:

[image]

```
identify -format "%[mean]" light.jpg
37265.7
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. This would work perfectly to suit my needs, but I can't manage to install Image::Magick on StrawberryPerl Win7 x64. Magick.xs:60:31: fatal error: magick/MagickCore.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Magick.o'
  JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.89-1.tar.gz
  Z:\strawberryperl_86\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK I was checking this: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25746&p=113771#p113771 but still could not fix it.

Comment: Not sure I can help there. I use ImageMagick at the commandline, with Perl and PHP on OS X. When I have used it on Windows I have used the commandline and always ActiveState Perl. Maybe try asking another question about getting IM installed on your Strawberry Perl - maybe not on SO as this about programming.

Comment: I'm searching a way to fix it right now. :) I'll reply back.

Comment: The range of pixel values depends on the "quantum depth" that is currently used (8, 16, or 32 bits). To write portable code, pixel values should be divided by the value returned by `Image::Magick->QuantumRange`.

Comment: @nwellnhof Yes, agreed, that would be more portable. Thank you.